# What is the best way to have a background be 4 equally sized images?

Tags: html

I'm looking for the simplest way to have 4 images take up 25% each of my background

Comment: 1-2-3-4 or 1-2\n3-4? or 1\n2\n3\n4 ? where \n = new line

Comment: The simplest way? Make them one image.

Comment: Well I can't do that because I want to add hover effects

Comment: Then I'd approach it with 4 elements inside the "one" element that is supposed to have this background. Each element has a diff bg img and hover effect.

Comment: Do you think this is the best way?

body { height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
div.bg { position:fixed; width:50%; height:50% }
#NW { top:0;   left:0;   background-image: url('clevelandnight.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#NE { top:0;   left:50%; background-image: url('news1.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#SW { top:50%; left:0;   background-image: url('drinks1.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
#SE { top:50%; left:50%; background-image: url('clevelandday.jpg'); background-size:cover;}

Comment: i made this: http://jsfiddle.net/tpf8mv51/6/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this a bit weird, but it's always worked for me.

css

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.pA, .pB, .pC, .pD {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
}
.pA {
    background: red;
}
.pB {
    background: green;
    margin-left: 50vw;
}
.pC {
    background: blue;
    margin-top: 50vh;
}
.pD {
    background: yellow;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    margin-left: 50vw;
}
```

and simple divs

```
<div class="pA">
</div>
<div class="pB">
</div>
<div class="pC">
</div>
<div class="pD">
</div>
```

it's simple, it works and it's easy to play with.

I'm guessing the **best** way (op's spec) would be to use `calc()` though.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jyge63jn/)